# Storing values from a list and dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have an issue with the last three lines of my code. I have a filtered list from the Alpaca API (shortable_marginable_assets). I then have an existing dictionary of tickers (symbol_list), and want to store only the tickers which are in both the filtered list and the dictionary.

```
    symbol_list = {
               'TSLA': 100,"NCLH": 100, "HTZ": 100,
               "UONE": 100, "MTL": 100, "NH": 100,
               "JFIN": 100, "CLDX": 100, "LMPX": 100,
               }

    for symbol in symbol_list:
        # Filter the assets which have passed all vola and price filters and are shortable based on Alpaca API
        final_universe = [a for a in shortable_marginable_assets if a.symbol == symbol]
        print(final_universe)

    final_universe_tickers = []

    for asset in final_universe:
        final_universe_tickers.append(asset["symbol"])
```

print(final_universe) gives the following format:

```
[Asset({   'class': 'us_equity',
    'easy_to_borrow': True,
    'exchange': 'NASDAQ',
    'id': '8ccae427-5dd0-45b3-b5fe-7ba5e422c766',
    'marginable': True,
    'name': 'Tesla, Inc. Common Stock',
    'shortable': True,
    'status': 'active',
    'symbol': 'TSLA',
    'tradable': True})]
[Asset({   'class': 'us_equity',
    'easy_to_borrow': True,
    'exchange': 'NYSE',
    'id': '81f61b55-adee-402e-87d4-7b49579e2338',
    'marginable': True,
    'name': 'Norwegian Cruise Line Holdings Ltd. Ordinary Shares',
    'shortable': True,
    'status': 'active',
    'symbol': 'NCLH',
    'tradable': True})]
[]
[]
etc.
```

Why is my final_universe_tickers variable empty when I run the code?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What should `final_universe_tickers` contain? `['TSLA', 'NCLH' ...]`?

Comment: yes, absolutely correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the `for asset in final_universe` loop into the `for symbol in symbol_list` loop as you are currently only looping over the *last* `final_universe`.

```py
final_universe_tickers = []

for symbol in symbol_list:
    # Filter the assets which have passed all vola and price filters and are shortable based on Alpaca API
    final_universe = [a for a in shortable_marginable_assets if a.symbol == symbol]
    print(final_universe)
    for asset in final_universe:
        final_universe_tickers.append(asset["symbol"])
```

Comment: ok, I had to make a small adjustment to your code: asset.symbol instead of asset["symbol"] in the last line. Then it worked.

Comment: @FM2020 Sorry I've never used that library before so I didn't know. I'm glad you managed to fix it! :D

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Now it says: TypeError: 'Asset' object is not subscriptable

This is the output from the console in Spyder IDE. Below a screenshot for the variable types.[image]

```
final_universe_tickers = []

for symbol in symbol_list:
    # Filter the assets which have passed all vola and price filters and are shortable based on Alpaca API
    final_universe = [a for a in shortable_marginable_assets if a.symbol == symbol]
    print(final_universe)
    for asset in final_universe:
        final_universe_tickers.append(asset["symbol"])
[Asset({   'class': 'us_equity',
    'easy_to_borrow': True,
    'exchange': 'NASDAQ',
    'id': '8ccae427-5dd0-45b3-b5fe-7ba5e422c766',
    'marginable': True,
    'name': 'Tesla, Inc. Common Stock',
    'shortable': True,
    'status': 'active',
    'symbol': 'TSLA',
    'tradable': True})]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-172-cbe6126e4f81>", line 8, in <module>
    final_universe_tickers.append(asset["symbol"])

TypeError: 'Asset' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0):

consider pulling the dictionary out of the asset object; not sure why alpaca has to present the data they way they do. I prefer to work dictionaries, rather than how alpaca presents it.

```
import alpaca_trade_api as tradeapi
api = tradeapi.REST(key_id=API_KEY,
                    secret_key=SECRET_KEY,
                    base_url='https://api.alpaca.markets',
                    api_version='v2',
                    oauth=None)

a = api.get_asset('NFLX')
print(a._raw)
print(a._raw['symbol'])

side note: if you do dir(response) you'll see a bunch of options you have with object. I chose _raw.
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattr__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_raw']
```